# How to display the graphic editor view of a Userform (after having closed it) in VBA?

Tags: vba, userform

I'm already sorry for the stupidity of my question.

Here is y problem :

1. I have created a macro in VBA for Word.
2. I have created a UserForm
   for display needs.
3. I have closed the graphic editor windows of the
   UserForm to open the code editor view.

Now I want want to add some commands to the UserForm so I'm looking for the button / shortcut to re-open the graphic editor
--> Can't find it (I've lost one hour of my poor life)

I've look in all the menu, I've looked for all the existing shortcuts, ... I've just found the shortcut "F7" to switch from the graphic edition to the code. I want the other way around. But hitting F7 again doesn't work.
I'm sure it's a stupid things my even stupider brain cannot figure it out.

There no code to show.
And I'm on Mac... with a French MS Word edition... sorry ...

Double click on the UserForm in the Project Explorer doesn't work
There's nothing in the right click menu
[screen shot of the right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZwhM.png)

Comment: Double click on the form in the project explorer.?

Comment: Doesn't work, it only open the code editor view

Comment: right click in the userform (in the project explorer) and view object ?

Comment: Double click works for me.

Comment: These is no "view object" option displayed in the right click menu

Comment: Are you in the form folder of your template project.

Comment: Also try a window.cascade as occasionally your firm can be off the visible screen when displayed.

Comment: Yes FreeFlow, I'm in this folder. I also checked the cascade display. I've even closed et re opened the file and I still can't get this $*€%ù Userform editor. 
I'm sure it's an obscure parameter to activate somewhere...